# Series Solution to Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, summation, power-series

Given the series $$1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\beta(\beta - 1) ... (\beta - k + 1)}{k!} x^k$$ how can I find a differential equation for which this series is a solution?

I don't have any idea how to think about this. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Call the series $f(x)$ and check that 
$$(1+x) \cdot f'(x) = \beta \cdot f(x)$$

Comment: this works!!! Like magic!!! Also is it possible to use this DE to find a non-series representation of $f(x)$?

Comment: I found it! just solving the differential equation gives the non-series representation of $f(x)$.

Comment: @user90593: All right!